# Decrease audio compression rate

Tags: c#, naudio

Hi I Want to Decrease the Compression rate/Playing Speed of My Audio Tracks in C# Using NAudio class, i.e. I want tracks to play at a slower speed than their original speed.

Previously I was using Windows Media Player object for just this thing and NAudio for everything else, but I want to shift completely to NAudio.

Answer (score 0):

NAudio does not have a built-in feature to do this. When I need to change playback rate, I create a managed wrapper around the [SoundTouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/) dll. I keep meaning to blog about how to do this, but for now, check out the [PracticeSharp](https://code.google.com/p/practicesharp/) project which also uses SoundTouch and NAudio.

Comment: For 40% decrease I am currently doing this using WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer class:


WindowsMediaPlayer obj=new WindowsMediaPlayer();

obj.URL = <My audio url>;

obj.settings.rate -= 0.4;

I don't know if this solves my purpose or not.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't need to intercept or manipulate raw PCM samples in any other way, that's probably an easier solution